# Can we do customized COALESCE() in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, coalesce

I've been using COALESCE since the first time I used BQ. So basically it looks for a non-NULL value within the bracket.

Is there any way for us to customize it? For example I have two fields that has values either ACTIVE or INACTIVE. I'd like to know whether one of the value from those fields is ACTIVE.

For example:

> - COALESCE('Inactive', 'Active') returns 'Active'
> - COALESCE('Active', 'Inactive') returns 'Active'
> - COALESCE('Inactive', 'Inactive') returns 'Inactive'

Is it possible to use any function for this purpose? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT 
  LEAST('Inactive', 'Active'), 
  LEAST('Active', 'Inactive'),
  LEAST('Inactive', 'Inactive')
```

with output

[image]

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the LEAST function will 'calculate' the STRING based on their alphabetical order, right?

Comment: correct! :o) so you can use LEAST or GREATEST depends on the context - this would perfectly work in your particular relatively simple case